# Scholarly sources for numeric symbolism in the Old and New Testaments?

Tags: hebrew-bible, numbers, new-testament, symbolism, history-of-hermeneutics

I'm wondering if anyone knows a good scholarly/academic source for the study of numbers and their significance in the Old and New Testaments? I often come across remarks about the Hebrew and/or Christian significance of different numbers, but they are always remarks in passing, and they never seem to provide any sources I can look into further. I would like to be able to substantiate these remarks with some good exposition of the primary sources and rationale for the attribution of various meanings to different numbers in the biblical literature.

Thank you in advance for your help!

In Christ,
Dan

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to understand how this site is different from others.

Comment: There have been huge books written on this subject and many Kabbalistic tomes and much ink wasted.  This is a highly debated area which many Christians regard as "humbug".

Comment: I have not read these, but a quick search on Amazon gave me these:

Number in Scripture - E.W. Bullinger,
The Meaning of Numbers in the Bible - Daisy E. Grove,
The Theology of Arithmetic: Number Symbolism in Platonism and Early Christianity - Joel Kalvesmaki

Comment: Thanks, Jason! Dottard, I'm aware of some of the more extravagant Kabbalistic interpretations of number, and that's not what I'm interested in. I'm referring specifically to literary, authorially intended symbolism and significance of numbers, e.g. Gen 21:31, "Therefore that place was called Be'er-she'ba ['Well of seven' or 'Well of the oath']; because there both of them [Abraham and Abimelech] swore an oath," in this case one involving seven ewe lambs.